# Subclassing a Keras Layer: The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call, but are not present in its tracked objects

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am making a custom convolutional layer by [subclassing a Keras Layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers). I did this with a previous version of Tensorflow, and received no warnings:

```
import tensorflow as tf


class MyCustomLayer(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels,
                 filters,
                 kernel_size,
                 padding,
                 strides,
                 activation,
                 kernel_initializer,
                 bias_initializer,
                 use_bias):
        super(MyCustomLayer, self).__init__()
        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.activation = activation
        self.padding = padding
        self.kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer
        self.bias_initializer = bias_initializer
        self.strides = strides
        self.use_bias = use_bias
        self.in_channels = in_channels

        self.w = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=self.kernel_initializer(shape=(*self.kernel_size,
                                                         in_channels,
                                                         self.filters),
                                 dtype='float32'), trainable=True)
        if self.use_bias:
            self.b = tf.Variable(
                initial_value=self.bias_initializer(shape=(self.filters,),
                                                    dtype='float32'),
                trainable=True)

    def __call__(self, inputs, training=None):
        x =  tf.nn.conv2d(inputs,
                          filters=self.w,
                          strides=self.strides,
                          padding=self.padding)
        if self.use_bias:
            x = tf.add(x, self.b)
        x = self.activation(x)
        return x


x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 3))
y = MyCustomLayer(
            in_channels=3,
            filters=16,
            kernel_size=(3, 3),
            strides=(1, 1),
            activation=tf.nn.relu,
            padding='VALID',
            kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
            bias_initializer=tf.initializers.Zeros(),
            use_bias=True)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
```

I'm getting this warning, with `tf.__version__ == 2.4.1`:

> WARNING:tensorflow:
> The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (tf.compat.v1.nn.conv2d_12), but
> are not present in its tracked objects:
> <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 16) dtype=float32>
> It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
> an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
> formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.

> WARNING:tensorflow:
> The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (tf.math.add_2), but
> are not present in its tracked objects:
> <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>
> It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
> an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
> formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.

What does this mean? I **am** using a subclassed Layer.

Comment: Did you solve this issue by any chance ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some hint. I've found a [blog](https://programming.vip/docs/day-6-tensorflow2-model-subclassing-api.html) where it discussed this. It states

> **tf.keras.Lambda**:  Note that if variables are involved in the layer created by this method, the variable will not be automatically added to the variable set for gradient calculation. Therefore, if there are parameters to be trained in the user-defined layer, it is recommended to customize the model layer based on the base class.

They showed

```
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((4, 2)), name='w')
bias = tf.ones((1, 2), name='b')
print(bias)
x_input = tf.range(12.).numpy().reshape(-1, 4)

# lambda custom layer
mylayer1 = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights),
                                                           bias), name='lambda1')
mylayer1(x_input)

tf.Tensor([[1. 1.]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (lambda1), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'w:0' shape=(4, 2) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 2.54332  ,  1.5078725],
       [ 0.5291851, -1.1049112],
       [ 1.475109 , -1.6525942],
       [ 1.593746 , -0.4049823]], dtype=float32)>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[  9.260641 ,  -4.6250463],
       [ 33.82608  , -11.243508 ],
       [ 58.391525 , -17.861969 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

They also showed a way to bypass the warning. But I'm not sure (yet) what could be done to bypass in your case. A Quick surveying on source code of [tf.compat.v1.nn.conv2d](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L2173-L2292), lead to a [lambda](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L560) expression that might be the cause.

```
 def build_op(num_spatial_dims, padding):
    return lambda inp, _: op(inp, num_spatial_dims, padding)
```